# Working with multiple values for a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
LOANWOLF_BANK_ACCOUNTS_LENGTH = {
        '001': 7,       # Banque de Montréal
        '002': 7,       # Scotia
        '003': 7,       # RBC
        '004': 7 or 11, # TD (7 or 11)
        '006': 7,       # BNC
        '010': 7,       # CIBC
        '016': 9,       # HSBC
        '039': 9,       # Banque Laurentienne
        '614': 10,      # Tangerine
        '815': 7,       # Desjardins
        '829': 7,       # Desjardins Ontario
    }
```

and

```
def clean_bank_account(self):
    bank_account = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank_account')
    bank_transit = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank_transit')
    if bank_account not in (None, ''):
        bank = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank')
        if bank not in (None, ''):

            # Check bank account format for specific banks
            length = settings.LOANWOLF_BANK_ACCOUNTS_LENGTH.get(bank)
            if length:
                if bank_transit not in (None, ''):
                    if not bank_account.isnumeric() or length != len(bank_account):
                        if bank == '004':
                            raise ValidationError(
                                _('Bank account number must contain 7 or 11 digits') % length  # noqa
                            )
                        else:
                            raise ValidationError(
                                _('Bank account number must contain %d digits') % length  # noqa
                            )
                else:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _('Cannot validate bank account without a valid bank transit')  # noqa
                    )
    return bank_account
```

I wanted to give more than one arguments, definitions to `004` so that if `length` is different of 7 or 11, then I want to display `Bank account number must contain 7 or 11 digits`. How could I pass more than one arguments to a keyword?

Comment: you can assign a list to a dictionary key, ` {'004': [7, 11]}`

Comment: @Dalvenjia if I change `'004' : 7 or 11` to `'004': [7, 11]`, it didn't work. Could you modify my code so that it works?

Comment: Hi, I noticed you revoked your acceptance. Can I help you with anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having your dictionary store a mapping of `<bankId : set>`, where each set contains possible lengths:

```
LOANWOLF_BANK_ACCOUNTS_LENGTH = {
             '001': {7},       # Banque de Montréal
             '002': {7},       # Scotia
             '003': {7},       # RBC
             '004': {7, 11}, # TD (7 or 11)
             '006': {7},       # BNC
             '010': {7},       # CIBC
             '016': {9},       # HSBC
             '039': {9},       # Banque Laurentienne
             '614': {10},      # Tangerine
             '815': {7},       # Desjardins
             '829': {7},       # Desjardins Ontario
         }
```

Your code will now need to test for set membership, like this:

```
 ( len(bank_account) not in length )
```

You can also simplify your error handling by using `str.format`.

```
...
if length:
    if bank_transit not in (None, ''):
        if not bank_account.isnumeric() or (len(bank_account) not in length): # this is the important part
            raise ValidationError(
                    _('Bank account number must contain {} digits').format(' or '.join(map(str, length)))  # noqa
                )

    else:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Cannot validate bank account without a valid bank transit')  # noqa
        )
...
```